# ORA-01843: not a valid month not getting resolved

Tags: oracle, date

I have a Oracle query in which I am getting error as

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

I tried using `to_date` also but still it didn't worked for me

Below is the query

```
INSERT INTO xxcus.xxacl_land_purc_invoice_view
        (mkey, ref_purchase_id, ref_sr_no, ref_purhcase_type, org_id,
         project_id, taluka_id, village_id, survey_area_7_12, doc_no,
         invoice_id, invoice_num, vendor_id, vendor_name, invoice_amt,
         batch_id, batch_name, exp_id, exp_type, remarks, created_by,
         creation_date, last_update_date, last_updated_by
        )
 VALUES (139, 18, 1, 'E', 6089,
         49292, 1, 14, '85/47', '693',
         NULL, NULL, 2653609, 'K.A.JOSEPH', 1000,
         572727, 'ICICI', 900077, 'Land Cost', 'TEST', 5681,
         '18-02-2017 16:02:10', '18-02-2017 16:02:10', '5681'
        )
```

Comment: Don't remove `to_date()`. Just use it properly.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: I used it but still it was not working . like this `to_date('18-02-2017 16:02:10', 'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: How could it work? Your data does not match the format at all.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: I m stuck at `sysdate` part. :(

Comment: What I mean is that `18-02-2017 16:02:10` does not match `dd-MM-yyyy`. (Your question says nothing about sysdate, are you asking new questions as previous ones get answered?):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use to_date with proper format mask:

```
to_date('18-02-2017 16:02:10','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO xxcus.xxacl_land_purc_invoice_view
        (mkey, ref_purchase_id, ref_sr_no, ref_purhcase_type, org_id,
         project_id, taluka_id, village_id, survey_area_7_12, doc_no,
         invoice_id, invoice_num, vendor_id, vendor_name, invoice_amt,
         batch_id, batch_name, exp_id, exp_type, remarks, created_by,
         creation_date, last_update_date, last_updated_by
        )
 VALUES (139, 18, 1, 'E', 6089,
         49292, 1, 14, '85/47', '693',
         NULL, NULL, 2653609, 'K.A.JOSEPH', 1000,
         572727, 'ICICI', 900077, 'Land Cost', 'TEST', 5681,
         to_date('18-02-2017 16:02:10','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
         to_date('18-02-2017 16:02:10','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
         '5681'
        )
```

As per OP's mention about inserting current datetime, it's better to use `sysdate`:

```
INSERT INTO xxcus.xxacl_land_purc_invoice_view
        (mkey, ref_purchase_id, ref_sr_no, ref_purhcase_type, org_id,
         project_id, taluka_id, village_id, survey_area_7_12, doc_no,
         invoice_id, invoice_num, vendor_id, vendor_name, invoice_amt,
         batch_id, batch_name, exp_id, exp_type, remarks, created_by,
         creation_date, last_update_date, last_updated_by
        )
 VALUES (139, 18, 1, 'E', 6089,
         49292, 1, 14, '85/47', '693',
         NULL, NULL, 2653609, 'K.A.JOSEPH', 1000,
         572727, 'ICICI', 900077, 'Land Cost', 'TEST', 5681,
         sysdate,
         sysdate,
         '5681'
        )
```

Comment: but I am sending like this in server side. then how should I add `to_date` ... Here it is `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: @nad - If you want to insert datetime as of "now", then use `sysdate`. I've edited my answer. Please check the second SQL.

Comment: but `sysdate` needs to be assigned something.. should I add like this `"SYSDATE"` ?

Comment: @nad - No. It's an Oracle builtin feature. You don't need to assign anything to it. Just simply use it. It'll get the current datetime automatically.

Comment: thanku, it was `sysdate` . I just needed to check the double quotes properly.